# Why does #pragma warning(push,0) enable additional warnings in MSVC 2015?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, compiler-warnings

MCVE:

```
#pragma warning(push,0)
#include <QWidget>
#pragma warning(pop)

#include <QVariant>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
}
```

compiling with Visual Studio 2015 (choose "Qt Application" as project type if it matters) and /W4 i get 2x`Warning C4100 (unreferenced formal parameter)` for `argc` and `argv` which is what i expect and are actually interested in. But in addition i get 5x`Warning C4251(class X needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of struct Y)` somewhere inside `qvariant.h`.

With different included files from Qt i can produce different warnings, so it's not just C4251. I was not able to reproduce it with standard library includes yet. The warnings disappear if i remove/comment the `#pragma warning`-lines or set the projects /W flag to a lower level. The level pushed seems to have no effect, so e.g. with /W0 and `#pragma warning(push,4)` i get no warnings.

What i would have expected is, that `#pragma warning(push,0)` disables all warnings inside `<QWidget>` and `#pragma warning(pop)` restores the initial state. Instead, Visual Studio seems to somehow detect that those files are from an external library (or is it something inside the Qt code?), but as soon as there is a push/pop pair the pushed warning-level is ignored and instead the initially set warning level via /W flag is used.

I came across this problem initially when using CMake and [cotire](https://github.com/sakra/cotire), which automatically generates a header file to be used as precompiled header. So in my code i don't use `#pragma warning (push/pop)` which compiles fine without Qt-Warnings. But the generated file wraps the includes in a push/pop pair and thus generates about 200 Warnings in my project. I'm trying to understand why this happens in order to find a solution which requires me neither to wrap all my manual includes in push/pop nor to maintain a private modification to cotire.

Comment: Could the problem be that `warning(push,n)` sets level `n`, but there isn't a warning level 0?

Comment: Hmm, this does not add up very well.  C4100 is a level 4 warning, you'd need /W4 to see it.  So maybe the warning level just is not what you think it is.  Maybe you shouldn't try so hard, C4251 is a *very* serious warning and very likely to blow up.

Comment: @BoPersson, the pushed warning level makes no difference until i increase it to 5, at which point i get the warning that 5 is no warning level ;)

Comment: @HansPassant the problem is, i get hundreds of warnings in the real code, most of them beeing things like "possible loss of precision" or "unreferenced formal parameter". Up to now i found none thats actually serious, especially since i would have to modify Qt code to get rid of them. C4251 might get serious, but in this (empty) example it warns about some private PIMPL classes....

Comment: @HansPassant seems like i mixed it up a bit during all the testing, you are right, C4100 only shows up with /W4, but the C4251 show up with /W2 and up, ignoring the push(0).